# Is the following infinite series convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Test the series for convergence and divergence
> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[\frac{\log (n)}{\log(n+1)}\right]^{n^2\log(n)}$$

I calculated the $n$-th term and found the limiting value for $n$ tending to infinity and it was a $1^\infty$ format thus the limiting value has to be non-zero, therefore it should be diverging; am I correct?

Comment: It's my first question here everyone, sorry if I didn't use any cool symbols or it was a bad question.

Comment: I have given you the cool symbols. : )

Comment: The limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n^2}$ is equal to $0$, in spite of being of the type $1^\infty$.